# Gradle build stuck while using symja library

Tags: android, gradle, symja

Gradle build is stuck while running project.

I have included symja-2015-08-09.jar file in libs folder.

I have no other dependencies and no other external jar files.

Can anyone please suggest any solution.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

The app runs fine after removing the jar file.

Has anyone used symja libraries in their android projects before?

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Gradle build keeps running for hours whenever I Run the project. There are no errors while building the project.

Comment: do you have internet connection enabled. Or you are in offline mode. Cause sometimes it downloads dependency while executing build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

You can try, clean the project then rebuild it. It may work. But first of all make sure you have installed proper android SDK

Comment: Your answer is not really an answer, but more of a suggestion.  It would be more appropriate to post this as a comment on the question itself.

Comment: I have tried all possible combinations of cleaning, rebuilding and making the project. Jar file is compatible with SDK as it would have generated an error otherwise.